# I am trying to retrieve BLOB data(image) and display in html page using servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, blob

I am trying to retrieve BLOB data(image) and display in html page using servlet.
Following is my code. But it displays nothing. Thanks in advance.
In addition I have used MySQL database.

```
public class retriveLogo extends HttpServlet {
standardFunction sf = new standardFunction();
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        Blob imageBlob=null;
        byte[] imgData = null;
    try {
            String sql1 = "select img from userLogo where userID=?";
            PreparedStatement statement = sf.co.con.prepareStatement(sql1);
            statement.setString(1, (String)session.getAttribute("User"));
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            while(resultSet.next())
            {
                imageBlob = resultSet.getBlob("doc");
                imgData = imageBlob.getBytes(1, (int) imageBlob.length());imageBlob.length());
            }
            OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
            response.setContentType("image/gif");
            output.write(imgData);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            try {
                sf.co.con.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException ex1) {
                Logger.getLogger(insertPaperSize.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            }
            Logger.getLogger(insertPaperSize.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }
```

I want to call it like

```
<img src="retriveLogo">
```

Comment: You get errors, or simply don't dispay anything? Where is Html code?

Comment: Sorry not in html page, in a jsp page. I want to use this servelet as src of a <img> tag. Somthing like <img src="retriveLogo"></img>

Comment: ok, post a snippet of jsp page

Comment: how can i do that???

Comment: you can edit original post

Comment: I am really very confused now. Is it really a tough problem that nobody is trying to help me. I thought there is a very minor problem in the code.